# Installing Ruby on Rails on Linux mint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, linux-mint

When I used "`sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential`" in the terminal I got this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential    
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.medibuntu.org_dists_quantal_non-free_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Can anybody tell me how can I install Ruby on Rails in my Linux Mint machine?

Comment: It looks like you've got bigger problems with your package management system that you'll likely want to resolve, but I recommend using [RVM](http://rvm.io/) to install Ruby. It takes the pain out of dealing with varying Linux distributions and their painfully-outdated collection of Ruby gems. You'll still end up needing system development libraries at some point, so you'll need to fix whatever the root problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't need features of rvm. You just want to install ruby easy, fast and without troubles, right? Good news to you. We got an alternative to rvm. It's called [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). You can find an installation guide [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation).(don't skip ruby-build, it is necessary!).

And yes, follow ubuntu instructions since Mint is build on it (though there's debian-based version but I suppose you use ubuntu-based one).

I installed yesterday Mint 16 and rbenv on it. Works fine.

PS: don't forget to `sudo apt-get install build-essential` first.

Comment: ok when i try this "sudo apt-get install build-essentials" first in terminal got$ sudo apt-get install build-essentials
[sudo] password for u107: 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.medibuntu.org_dists_quantal_non-free_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Can you please tell why i got this?

Comment: @user2640758 look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err) please.

Comment: Yes that works fine sir .ok after installation finishes how can i use ruby commands.like [-e "puts 'Hello,Theres!'" ]

Comment: @user2640758 When you install rbenv with ruby-build type `rbenv install 2.1.0-preview1 && rbenv rehash`. Then type `irb` in your terminal and go use ruby commands. Also you can create file `file_name.rb`, write your commands where and run it from terminal by `ruby file_name.rb`

Comment: @user2640758 after `rbenv install` run `rbenv global 2.1.0-preview1`

Comment: sir i first type command in terminal sudo apt-get install ruby 1.9.1
by this it gets install and and when i check it by typing it returns ->http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/products/view_product/nokia-internet-stick-cs-17-hsdpa-144mbps-logo-nokia-black-1

Comment: is it means i can use ruby?

Comment: $ git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git $HOME/.rbenv i have done this

Comment: For me I had to install with sudo apt-get install build-essential without the "s" in the end

Answer (score 2):

I actually use Mint on my main development system.  I'd also recommend using [RVM](http://rvm.io) to manage all your Ruby and Rails installation/versions.  The command to install it is:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

You can also append `--ruby` and `--rails` to get (I believe) the most recent versions of the two of them.  I'd recommend not using apt-get for installing Ruby, as I've noticed that it can be out of date and/or lead to strange errors like those that you're seeing.  You can get more information from the RVM website.  I really enjoy using Mint, so I hope that helps.

Comment: Does linux mint come with curl installed? I know my install of ubuntu did not. If not, I would first do `sudo apt-get install curl` and then try again `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: Yes sir i got this like as :-> u107@mint107 ~ $ sudo apt-get install curl
[sudo] password for u107: 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.medibuntu.org_dists_quantal_non-free_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: So you basically got the same error as before?  Sounds like there's a bigger problem with your package installer.  Can you use the Synaptic Package Manager instead of terminal?  Not sure if it'll help, but it's the only thing I can think of as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use rvm to install Ruby then simply install rails gem , but before that fix your repository related problem.

`sudo rm -rf /var/log/apt/list
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then install rvm see rvm.io for installation info
If you are new want to setup everything from start then see this blog post 
https://www.computersnyou.com/4235

Answer (score 0):

Use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv)
instead, use this link [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04) since mint is an ubuntu based distro, it will work.